# eclipse cannot import project from open file system?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have imported this project before and it was ok but later on changing jre libraries or deleting metafolder, don't know what I did or it's a bug.
It started giving errors and I deleted this project.
Now I again on restarting this project from different file location but still getting error.

Don't really know what really happened exactly but this was the error I am receiving in pop up .

[image]

```
  !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2018-12-13 10:55:49.034
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\abc'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 0 2018-12-13 10:56:18.878
!MESSAGE Could not import project located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Futronic\SDK 4.2\Examples\Java
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.CouldNotImportProjectException: Could not import project located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Futronic\SDK 4.2\Examples\Java
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.SmartImportJob.toExistingOrNewProject(SmartImportJob.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.SmartImportJob.run(SmartImportJob.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not write file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Futronic\SDK 4.2\Examples\Java\.project.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openOutputStream(LocalFile.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.write(FileSystemResourceManager.java:1159)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.internalWrite(FileSystemResourceManager.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.writeDescription(Project.java:1365)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.writeDescription(Project.java:1346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.create(Project.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.create(Project.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.SmartImportJob.createOrImportProject(SmartImportJob.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.SmartImportJob.toExistingOrNewProject(SmartImportJob.java:505)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Futronic\SDK 4.2\Examples\Java\.project (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openOutputStream(LocalFile.java:400)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: It looks like Eclipse don't have write permission in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Futronic\SDK 4.2\Examples\Java` causing this issue.

Comment: so how should i get permissions for that.

Comment: By changing the permissions in Windows or by moving/copying the `Examples` folder to e. g. the `Desktop` or into the `Documents`. (By default, in `C:\Program Files (x86)` write permissions are limited to an administrator.)

Comment: i had to move from C : program files to any where else desktop or downloads and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue is caused by **Eclipse doesn't have write permission** to create a file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Futronic\SDK 4.2\Examples\Java` (when doing *File > Open Projects from File System...* missing file like `.project` that are required by Eclipse are created).

**Adding write permission** for the normal user or **moving/copying** the folder to open **to the *Desktop* or to the *Documents*** folder should solve this issue (by default, in Windows in `C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\Program Files` files can be created only as admin).